# Focus out event of asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to call a javascript function on focus out of asp.net textbox.
I want to do this on client side and not on server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" onblur="myFunction()" />
```

However, you should really use a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to attach the events rather than doing them inline:

```
$('#<%=textbox1.ClientID %>').blur(function() {
     // implementation here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox>
```

JQuery

```
$('#<%=txt1.ClientID %>').blur(function() {
  alert('Handler for .blur() called.');
});
```

Comment: This is a rather convoluted way of doing this - why not just use the ID as is?  Much better to use the onblur property as per the other answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" onblur="myFunction">
```

This will give you the event args also on the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jQuery syntax to find any elements that END with the unique portion of your ID.

```
$("[id$='textbox1']")).blur(function() {   
  alert('Handler for .blur() called.'); 
});
```

Depends on what functionality you are going for...

Also, if you have 1.4.3 or later of jQuery, you can use the focusout event (same concept as .blur, except it bubbles events up).